# The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context in c#

Tags: c#

```
TruncateData("Order");
TruncateData("Customer");

context.Customers.Add(new Customer(fields));
//  context.Employees.Add(new Employee(fields));
context.SaveChanges();

fillComboBox();

public void TruncateData(String table)
{
    context.Database.
        ExecuteSqlCommand
        ("Delete from [dbo].[" + table + "]" + $" DBCC CHECKIDENT('{table}', RESEED, 0)");
    context.SaveChanges();

}
```

I'm reading file from csv files to database in C# and I am uploading to database using Entity Framework. Before inserting the values I'm truncating the data so it primary key starts from 1 every time. But I am getting this error.

Here s my error:

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The `ObjectContext` might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type `ProjectTeam03ElectricStore.EF_Classes.Customer` have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption` fluent API or `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute` for Code First configuration.

Comment: If your `Customer` table contains identity column, seems that you need to set `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `Identity` (DB/Model First) or adding attribute `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` (Code First) to prevent insertion of duplicate PKs.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto can you please tell me how to do that. I don't know much about that